# Ext.form.field.ComboBox shows HTML in Firefox

Tags: extjs

I have the following code which works on all browsers except Firefox:

```
{
    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
    dataIndex: 'action',
    flex: 1,
    text: 'Action',
    editor: new Ext.form.field.ComboBox({
        typeAhead: true,
        triggerAction: 'all',
        selectOnTab: true,
        store: [
            ['Update','Update'],
            ['Suspend','Suspend'],
            ['Cancel','Cancel']
        ],
        lazyRender: true,
        listClass: 'x-combo-list-small',
        listeners: {
            change:{
                scope: me,
                fn: me.processAction
            },
            focus: function(combo) {
                combo.expand();
            },
            collapse: function(combo) {
                //combo.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

The problem is that when you click on the combo box, the first item in the list is `<div id="ext-gen1584" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">&nbsp;</div>`.

Has anyone else encountered this?  Is it a bug in Ext or in Firefox?

Currently testing in Firefox 18.0.2.

Comment: Good find. I guess the only thing you can do is submit it to the Sencha forums.

Answer (score 1):

I had this bug, like the others said, it happens when you haven't dataIndex's field in model. But here's one little moment, that you HAVE to initialize that field in model, even by empty value, and then it will render correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  < 5.0 versions have bug in firefox - when dataIndex have invalid name, editor got wrong value.

---

[**Just look example**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/but)

---

```
header: 'Relationship',
dataIndex: 'relationshipWRONG', // rename this on 'relationship'
flex: 2,
getEditor: function() {
    return Ext.create('Ext.grid.CellEditor', {
        field: Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
            store: relativeStore,
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'name',
            editable: false
        })
    });
}
```

Look at this in chrome and firefox, in firefox you see dom element instead null value. In 5 verion all is well. 
Rename this dataindex and value will be correct.

But i seen this bug when dataIndex is correct on datacolumn, and i have not found how to resolve it and just changing value in **beforestartedit** event(ofc it's bad practise)

Answer (score -1):

I have meet similar problem in grid,if the dataIndex have no value,then the cell will show what you have seen..so pls check the content of the dataIndex:Action;

Comment: No, sorry, dataIndex is set for each fields here. The add() function for the store set the value to "" and onDrop the value is undefined.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I figured out today in my case...

In a scenario where you have

1 - a store with fields 'id', 'name', 'displayName' with a combo on displayName field.

> in response to daixfnwpu: **AND dataIndex is set for each field.**

2 - a record to add with fields 'id', 'name' but NO displayName in it.

If you do a store.add(record), this seems to work and displayName will be set to an empty string ""

But if you drag-drop the record, the drop action does not seem to set the displayName and it stays undefined... This is a source of problems...

I fixed this by filtering the added records onDrop...

```
Ext.each(records, function(record) {
    var displayName = record.get('displayName');
    record.set('displayName', displayName ? displayName : '');
    record.commit();
});
```